# Have Heat Maps and/or Mouse Tracking led to improved conversion rates in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, design, testing, user

I need to confirm or disprove some assumptions on navigation and layout for new RWD design. Looking at new tools to provide some useful data. Have enough traffic to run 5000+ tests per page.

Question is, from experience, is there a preferred collection method (heat maps or mouse tracking) for Magento that delivers actionable results without causing issues w/design, js, performance, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Google analytics has in-page analytics that can heat map clicks for you, but afaik it doesn't heat-map mouse movement

Comment: There are many repeated links on some category and home pages(buttons, text links, banners) and Google Analytics does not differentiate which specific one was actually clicked. Shows a combined number. Need more specific tracking

Comment: @Blake take at GA Enhanced Link Attribution ...https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en

Comment: Hello R.S. I'll take a look at that. Have you implemented it and found it useful?

Comment: I know this is nearly a year old. But in case anyone still looking. There are 2 I just discovered. heatmap.me (heat mapping only has a generous free offering IMO) and luckyorange.com probably the best pricing I've seen over any heatmap/analytics service. Currently testing both. I'm planning on doing a template update myself so this should be helpful for me. And hopefully plan to do some AB testing in the near future and compare the heatmap data.

Comment: @ZenMasta Any luck with either of those options? I'm revisiting this again

Answer (score 1):

In the past we have used [Econda](http://www.econda.de/) for this sort of heat map tracking. It has many great features but I guess for your needs the [click monitoring](http://www.econda.com/web-analytics/click-monitor/) would work.

There is also a free Magento plugin but the service itself is paid but has a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://vwo.com/blog/magento-ab-testing/ or CrazyEgg and a few others here http://topalternatives.com/heatmaps-and-click-tracking-analytics/. It's all business specific - what works for one will cause headaches for the next.

Comment: Thanks for the links @serpyre. Have you used either CrazyEgg (heat map) or Inspectlet (mouse track + heat map) w/Magento?


Only looking for user behavior but will check out VMO later when doing a/b.